# Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by

Tags: login

When I open my blog the error appears at the top. And none of the photos load either. My site is lifelong.ca

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /home1/jgosl762/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1) in
>   /home1/jgosl762/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-limit-login-attempts/wp-limit-login-attempts.php
>   on line 66
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /home1/jgosl762/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:1) in
>   /home1/jgosl762/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-limit-login-attempts/wp-limit-login-attempts.php
>   on line 66

Comment: Hey, this is not a customer support website, but a hub for developers. Go to the developer's support page and ask: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-limit-login-attempts/

Answer (score 0):

Do you still get the error when you DE-activate that plugin wp-login-attempts?  If you just started getting this it may be that it's not compatible with an update you did to wordpress.

Try deactivating that plugin.